# use of * in file searching

Tags: 14.04, filesystem

while reading about linux file searching I got the following...

To search for files using the * wildcard, replace the unknown string with *, e.g. if you remember only that the extension was .out, type ls *.out

and when I tried the following command on system(ubuntu 14.04 LTS) ..I got

```
anupam@JAZZ:~$ ls  *.bash* 

ls: cannot access  *.bash* : No such file or directory

anupam@JAZZ:~$ ls  .bash*

.bash_history   .bash_logout  .bash_profile  .bashrc

anupam@JAZZ:~$
```

in the first case why it is showing No such directory ( `*.bash*` ) and in next case its showing the files ( `.bash*` )

I am new to this flavor, and according to my automata theory classes (*) means any combination of strings including epsilon(empty),,So why the results are different in both the cases....?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you do `ls *` the `*` is being expanded *before* it is passed to `ls`. That is to say if we have three files (`a`, `b` and `c`) in a directory `ls *` is actually running `ls a b c`.

When Bash can't expand, it passes through the raw string¹. That's why you see the wildcards in the error, along with a not found message. `ls` tried to show the listing for a file literally called `*.bash*`.

So *why* didn't that expand? Well by default globbing (what this wildcard expansion is called) won't return hidden files. You can change this with `shopt -s dotglob` (that won't persist unless you stick it in your `.bashrc` — it might be disabled by default for a good reason so be careful with it), here's a quick demo:

```
$ ls  *.bash*
ls: cannot access *.bash*: No such file or directory
$ shopt -s dotglob
$ ls  *.bash*
.bash_aliases  .bash_history  .bash_logout  .bashrc  .bashrc.save
```

The exception to this is —as you've already shown— when you've already explicitly stated the files will be hidden with a pattern like `.bash*`. It simply overrides the default `dotglob` setting:

```
$ shopt -u dotglob  # unset dotglob
$ ls .bash*
.bash_aliases  .bash_history  .bash_logout  .bashrc  .bashrc.save
```

Anyway besides that quirk, I hope this helps you understand what's going on under the surface.

---

There are other `shopt` flags that alter how globbing works: `extglob`, `failglob`,  `globstar`, `nocaseglob` and `nullglob`. They and a raft of other `shopt` flags are  documented as part of [the Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html).

Similarly, the page on [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html) should make for some good reading.

¹ Unless `failglob` or `nullglob` are set.

Comment: thanx @Oli ,,I didn't get all of that as I mentioned I am new to this flavor,,but I got 80% of that...It helped me